convert m3u8 files to wpl files
i use windows media player for managing my playlists and music on my computer. however, i want to have the playlists on my android with me. for that matter, i have a media player app. this app can read wpl files, but will output m3u8 files upon extraction of the playlists. this format can not be read by windows media player, so i have to convert the m3u8 playlists into wpl files, to have changes made on my android phone mirrored to my pc.
I did not find any online converting services except those available for money, but i did not want to use those.

i wrote a python script that will convert the playlist files into wpl format that i wanted to share, just in case someone has the same problem
import os

import glob

script_folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
playlists_folder = script_folder.replace("\\\\", "/").replace("\\", "/") + "/../Playlists/"
playlists_file_pattern = "*.m3u8"
glob_pattern = playlists_folder + playlists_file_pattern
playlist_file_paths = glob.glob(glob_pattern, recursive=True)
for playlist_file_path in playlist_file_paths:
    with open(playlist_file_path) as playlist_file:
        try:
            lines = [line.rstrip() for line in playlist_file]
            output_lines = "<?wpl version=\"1.0\"?>\n<smil>\n    <head>    </head>\n    <body>\n        <seq>"
            for line in lines:
                if "#EXT-X-RATING:" in line:
                    continue
                if "#EXTM3U" in line:
                    continue
                replaced = line.replace("path/to/Music","<media src=\"..") + "\"/>"
                output_lines = output_lines + "\n" + replaced
            output_lines = output_lines + "        </seq>\n    </body>\n</smil>"
            new_file_path = playlist_file_path.replace("M3u8Playlists", "wplPlaylists").replace("m3u8", "wpl").replace("wpl.wpl", "wpl")
            with open(new_file_path, "w") as output_file:
                 output_file.write(output_lines)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"ERROR: File: '{playlist_file_path}'")
            print(e)


